# What's the best way to use IF and SWITCH together for game levels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, int, switch-statement

I have the following code working correctly in my game project where a ball is randomly shown to the player.

```
    int random = arc4random_uniform(5);

    switch (random)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 0 Ball");
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 1 Big Ball");
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 2 Center Ball");
            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 3 Red Ball");
            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 4 Blue Ball");
            break;
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is limit the number of potential balls shown to the player until the player achieves a certain level.  I think the simplest way to do this is with just changing the number of random cases.  So for instance...

```
    int random = arc4random_uniform(1);
    int random = arc4random_uniform(2);
    int random = arc4random_uniform(3);
    int random = arc4random_uniform(4);
    int random = arc4random_uniform(5);
```

Of course the problem is when I try to wrap those options in the `if statement` below, it separates it from the Switch, which won't work.

```
    int unlockBallLevel = [_levels getCurrentLevel];
    if (unlockBallLevel > 5) {
        int random = arc4random_uniform(5);
    }
```

I'm wondering what would be the most logical and efficient way to limit the number of balls until a certain level is reached?

Comment: To get you started: lookup `switch` and `default`, comparisons and `MIN()`. The ways to solve your problem are many.

Comment: Saying there are many ways to solve this problem doesn't help lead to the most logical and efficient solution.  I'm not at a level to know all the possible combinations and reading myriad documents still may not give a clear picture to which method is the best or most efficient, which is why I posed the question here.

Comment: I'm not trying to be unkind, but you say you are writing a game and yet are stuck mapping a level number (1 -> 99) to a maximum number of balls (1 -> 5?)...? That doesn't quite add up to me. Anyway, what is the mapping, I'm not sure that is clear either? Maybe anything over 5 gets up to 5 balls (that is what @jeffamaphone's answer is giving you)? Try `maxNumberOfBalls = MIN(_levels.currentLevel, 5)`. Some other mapping? Reading is good for you BTW, though I do understand its not in fashion these days! ;-)

Comment: I understand you a little better now and where I created the confusion.  I was not trying to create a 1 to 1 mapping.  I was saying there are 5 things I want to unlock at points during the game.  I have posted a working version of what code I came up with to solve the problem.  That should help clarify my intentions.  And I agree, "Reading is Fundamental."  I'm old enough to remember physical book stores... Ah, those were the days. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @CRD's comments, I made the following changes to the code. The code below seems like a much more efficient and smarter implementation over the last answer posted.

```
    int unlockAtLevel = [_levels getCurrentLevel];

    if (unlockAtLevel >= 25)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 6;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    } else if (unlockAtLevel >= 20)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 5;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    } else if (unlockAtLevel >= 15)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 4;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    } else if (unlockAtLevel >= 10)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 3;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    } else if (unlockAtLevel >= 3)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 2;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    } else if (unlockAtLevel >= 1)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 1;
        [[GCHelper defaultHelper]reportAchievementIdentifier:achievementID1 percentComplete:100];
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }


    NSLog(@"\n\n###############################################################\n\nCurrently the player is on level %i so there should be %i main balls unlocked!\n\n###############################################################\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);

    int random = arc4random_uniform(ballsForRandom);

    switch (random)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
switch (arc4random_uniform([_levels getCurrentLevel] < 5 ?: 5)) 
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: There are more levels than there are switch cases.  The game will have at least 99 levels.  So once the player got pass level 5 the switch would have too large of a number.

Comment: then make a function that returns the max number of balls for each level, ie if levelnumber < 10 return 2 etc etc

Comment: Or include a default case.

Comment: I modified the answer to use 5 if current level is greater than 5.  This is basic stuff.

Comment: @jeffamaphone - You just know that writing "basic stuff" means you'll make an error... I think you'll find your modified version returns 1 or 5.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Thanks for your answer.  It didn't work but it got me thinking and I came up with this possible solution.  Not sure if there is a better way, but I think it will work.

        `int unlockAtLevel = [_levels getCurrentLevel];
        
        if (unlockAtLevel > 1) {

            ballsForRandom = 1;
        } else if (unlockAtLevel > 10){
            ballsForRandom = 2;
        }
        int random = arc4random_uniform(ballsForRandom);`

Comment: @StormFactory - you'll never find `unlockAtLevel > 10` to be true as if it is the first condition `unlockAtLevel > 1` will also be true and you'll set `ballsForRandom` to 1 and never reach the `else`. Sorry I can't tell you what to do as I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The last thing I posted did not work because I should have added greater than equals to with `if` and not greater than with `else if`.  I'll post an answer to show all the working code.

Comment: Thanks @CRD. The code is now posted.  If you see something wrong with it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  I still don't know if there is a more efficient way to doing this, but the following code works and unlocks more balls as the player levels up through level 75.  After level 75, all five balls are unlocked.

```
    int unlockAtLevel = [_levels getCurrentLevel];

    if (unlockAtLevel >= 1)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 1;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }
    if (unlockAtLevel >= 10)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 2;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }
    if (unlockAtLevel >= 30)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 3;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }
    if (unlockAtLevel >= 50)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 4;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }
    if (unlockAtLevel >= 75)
    {
        ballsForRandom = 5;
        NSLog(@"\n\nLevel %i reached! There are now %i main balls unlocked!\n\n",unlockAtLevel,ballsForRandom);
    }

    int random = arc4random_uniform(ballsForRandom);

    switch (random)

{
    case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 0 Ball");
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 1 Big Ball");
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 2 Center Ball");
        break;
    }

    case 3:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 3 Red Ball");
        break;
    }

    case 4:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 4 Blue Ball");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If, say, `unlockAtLevel` is 80 how many of your `NSLog`s get called? Might it be better if the answer was different? Just a thought.

Comment: There would be 5 `NSLog`s showing in the console at Level 80, but I could comment those out before I ship.  As I said, I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but it's one that works and doesn't cause errors or decrease performance.  With only 112 (used to be 114 before this post) reputation points I'm knowledgeable enough to know I'm not knowledgeable enough.  :-)

Comment: What would happen if you reversed the order of the tests and threw in some `else`s before some of those `if`s?

Comment: @CRD What would happen is it would work exactly the way I was envisioning. Thanks for the suggestion! I just posted the new code. Let me know what you think of the new answer.